# A question about "KeyDown"

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio and  I am writing Visual Basic

How do I write "If button is  pressed for one second" ?

Comment: I'll take that as Visual Basic 6 then. (Rather than Visual Basic.Net).

Comment: I took it the other way.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to require a timer.

- Set a timer to elapse after 1 second and enable it in keydown.
- On keyup disable the timer
- In the timer event put the code you want to happen after one second of keydown (but disable the timer first so it doesn't fire twice).

Note: you'll need to consider what you want to do in the case of multiple keydowns/presses as this makes this scenario harder.